# How to place " target='_blank' " in all Anchor (<a>) tags in a website?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

Is there any possebilities to do that... like jscript or any other method. and how to use it in blogger. But everything is welcome.

Comment: maybe it's better/faster/easier to do search and replace?

Answer (score 6):

If XHTML is a concern to you (as noted by the tags in the question), it's worth noting that target is not a valid attribute. Anyway, here's how you could do it with javascript.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
    links[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}
```

Comment: +1 but better is to cache `length` has `links` is a live collection thingy, meaning it gets reevaluated whenever you access a property of it. I normally just loop in reverse order if possible: `for(var i = links.length; i--; )`

Comment: @Felix, yup - but sometimes it's easier to just stick to "beginner" code to focus the answer on what's important

Comment: Target is not a valid attribute? Yes, it is. There is more to XHTML than XHTML 1.0 Strict.

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to make all the links open in a new window/tab, the standard way is to add this to the `<head>` section of your page:

```
<base target="_blank">
```

Comment: This works for me! And it's so simple I don't know why people would bother with doing it in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can do:

```
$("a").attr("target","_blank");
```

I'm not sure how this will sit with Blogger though as I don't know if you can use custom scripts...

Comment: Why do people give jQuery answers to JavaScript questions? It is not so difficult to do this without jQuery and just for this one line I would not load jQuery. I'm convinced you have good intentions but only providing the "jQuery way" is not good for this kind of questions.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Fair point I guess, although the question states '_jscript or any other method_' so I think this falls under the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var num = a.length;

for(i=1; i<=num; i++) {
    a[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}
```